# create one xml node from two functions php

Tags: php, xml

Im using the google map api with a database connection, I have a function that output an xml file and the JavaScript reads the coordinates . no problem there.

Now i want to add another function that prints out the users  that have saved coordinates in the db.

But my xml file prints out like this.

```
<blog title="Ipsum" text="IpsumLorem" lat="31.968599" lng="-99.901810"/>
<blog username="user1"/>
```

instead of printing user1 in the first row like this

```
<blog title="Ipsum" text="IpsumLorem" lat="31.968599" lng="-99.901810" username="user1" />
```

this is my two functions

```
function fetch_articles() {
    $query = $this->link->query("SELECT * FROM blog ");  
    $query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    while($row = $query->fetch()) {  
        $node = $dom->createElement("blog");  
    $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);   
    $newnode->setAttribute("title",$row['title']);
    $newnode->setAttribute("text", $row['text']);  
    $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);  
    $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['lng']);  
    } 
}

function fetch_users() {
    $query = $this->link->query("SELECT * FROM user ");  
    $query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    while($row = $query->fetch()) {  
        $node = $dom->createElement("blog");  
    $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);   
    $newnode->setAttribute("username",$row['username']);
    } 
}



 $area = new Areas();
$area_info = $area->fetch_articles(); 
$user_info = $area->fetch_users(); 
echo $dom->saveXML();
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Put the two functions' bodies into one function, then write an SQL query to look up blog entries and associated users, and add them to the same `blog` DOM element. If you need help with that, just ask. I'd need more information about your actual setup do answer that question in more detail.

Comment: In the second function name the element `user` instead of `blog`.

Comment: @likeitlikeit Something like this ? 

SELECT blog.title,blog.text,blog.lat,blog.lng, user.username FROM blog JOIN user

and the connect it to the user_id ?

Comment: @Dymond Exactly! Should I write that into an answer?

Comment: @likeitlikeit I just got it to work,! THANK YOU, sometimes you just need a little push! if you write it as an answer ill accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have lacks a way of connecting the users with the blog posts. Thus, it's probably easiest to just write a query that fetches both in a single result, then adds that to a DOM node. It could work like this:

```
function fetch_articles_with_username() {
    $query = $this->link->query("SELECT * FROM blog LEFT JOIN user WHERE blog.userid = user.id ");  
    $query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    while($row = $query->fetch()) {  
        $node = $dom->createElement("blog");  
        $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);   
        $newnode->setAttribute("title",$row['title']);
        $newnode->setAttribute("text", $row['text']);  
        $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);  
        $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['lng']);  
        $newnode->setAttribute("username",$row['username']);
    } 
}
```

You'd use it like above, just making a single call to `fetch_articles_with_username()`.

Comment: You have an undefined variable `$dom` inside your method - it does fatal-error on `$dom->createElement("blog");`.

Comment: @hakre Saw it tool. It's probably a global variable, I took it straight out of the asker's post.

Comment: Yes friends, its global variables, haven't found out how to solve that yet :)

Comment: @Dymond: You need to inject it. Don't fall into the global trap. You can also make it return a new domelement that you then import into a document later. Then you don't need `$dom` at all and only the name of the element is hardcoded.

Comment: @hakre wow, that sound a bit more nicer than i have for the moment, i need to read more about this. Will skip the globals as soon i understand on how to fix it :)

Comment: @Dymond: Actually I think the root-problem is located elsewhere: You have written the method without returning a value. So you have interdirect returns here. This is a sign you should only modify private members (internal state of the object). That also moves the global away (because it's a private member). And then all you need is a getter/setter pair to set the document object and the element name. But still I'd say this is doing too much :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to apply the attribute changes on the same `DOMElement`. Because both methods actually contain quite the same code, it's also worth to encapsulate that as well:

```
$blog = $dom->createElement("blog");

$apply = new DomAttributeApplyIterator(
    new PdoQueryIterator($pdo, "SELECT * FROM blog"), $blog
);
$apply->apply();

$apply = new DomAttributeApplyIterator(
    new PdoQueryIterator($pdo, "SELECT * FROM user"), $blog
);
$apply->apply();

echo $dom->saveXML();
```

The two new types used:

```
class DomAttributeApplyIterator extends IteratorIterator
{
    /**
     * @var DOMElement
     */
    private $element;

    public function __construct(Traversable $iterator, DOMElement $element) {
        parent::__construct($iterator);
        $this->element = $element;
    }

    public function apply() {
        foreach($this as $key => $value) {
            $this->element->setAttribute($key, $value);
        }
    }
}

class PdoQueryIterator implements IteratorAggregate
{
    private $pdo, $query;

    public function __construct(PDO $pdo, $query) {
        $this->pdo = $pdo;
        $this->query = $query;
    }

    public function getIterator() {
        $stmt = $this->pdo->query($this->query);
        $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $stmt;
    }
}
```

Comment: That looks interesting, but how does it actually solve the question?

Comment: By moving the blog-element creation out of the database query functionality.

Comment: really interesting solution, i will def. try it. Thank you @hakre

Comment: This is cool! I think the original problem was that there was a `JOIN` missing in the original version, as the results from the blog table and the users table don't match up. Food for though for me, though...

Comment: Start by looking at the duplicate code inside your two functions. Consider how to move that into a central place.

Comment: @likeitlikeit: Even with a join (and some field aliases probably), my code should still work without changing any line of code (just some SQL). Not saying that JOIN can not be a perfect solution here, your solving-view looks good :)

Comment: Arrgh :) , my answer might be wrong, because this needs a double apply for multiple rows. So the blog element creation might need to go inside a loop first. So probably only JOIN is the solution *or* you need the multiple Iterator here: http://php.net/multipleiterator

Comment: @hakre Thanks for showing me something new on a slow Sunday afternoon! I didn't know that this could be achieved in this basically simple, elegant way.